# Date safety: is data collected and not shared or data collected and shared when using Google Admob / Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-play-console, firebase-analytics

For example I use Firebase Crashlytics in my apps and I need to set that my apps collect crash logs.

I have two options (*Collected* and *Shared*) there but which one should I choose or both?

Also If I choose *Collected* option then I have additional questions like:

> Yes, this collected data is processed ephemerally
>
> No, this collected data is not processed ephemerally

But I have no idea how Firebase stores the data, it's not my own server.

So it seems I should choose *Collected* option, just *Shared*, correct?

[image]

If I select *Collected* and not *Shared* then I see the following preview of Data Safety before submitting it:

> The developer says this app doesn’t share user data with other
> companies or organizations

[image]

But what about Google company?

**Update**:

My app doesn't have authorization and doesn't have any my own servers to connect expect using third-party libraries like Google Admob, Firebase (default Analytics without custom events, Crashlytics, Remote Config, FCM/Messaging) which connect to their own servers and so on.

So If I use such libraries then my app collects (or shares, or both, unknown) the following data:

- Approximate location (Admob? UMP SDK? Firebase Remote Config? Firebase Analytics?)
- Crash logs (CrashLytics), Diagnostics (Admob?)
- App interactions (Admob? Firebase In-App Messaging? Firebase Analytics? CrashLytics?)
- Device or other IDs (Admob and I guess each Firebase service we use uses it)

So for example the following data are used for the Admob/Firebase (third-party) libs and I should specify that this data "Collected" or "Shared" or both, how should I answer it for each data in Data Safety section on Google Play Console website?

I found the following link https://github.com/Privado-Inc/SDK-Privacy-Report/blob/main/Android%20App%20-%20SDK%20Privacy%20Report.csv

Many Google (Admob/Firebase) libraries there marked as both "Collected" and "Shared". Is it correct? Should I do the same for my app, set both like in the specified table?

Also I checked [the official docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10787469?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdata-collection) but it's confusing:

[image]

[image]

So it's unclear, it just says that if we use third-party libs then the data is collected and shared in both cases anyway. Or what do they mean?

How can I even know what Google/Firebase libs share or not?

Then I decided to check official Google app - YouTube which definitely uses Admob (ads in videos) and some data should be shared I believe between advertisement partners of Admob but then I found that they specified that they only collect the data and don't share it:

[image]

Why so?

It just drives me crazy.

I know that actually many developers don't really fill this info accurately and usually they would just specify that only "Device or other IDs" is used for advertisement (Admob) when actually there are much more data is used by Admob.

So which data is actually collected and shared or just collected?

YouTube app definitely uses the same services Admob and Firebase libs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Final decision (answer) would be:

If we use any Google library (Admob/Firebase) then the data is both collected and **SHARED** in our apps:

> You are not Google therefore you are sharing data with Google who are
> a 3rd party to your app. If you wrote your own analytics software and
> hosted it on your servers then you would not be sharing data.

But many developers specify for their apps that they only collect the data but don't share it which is totally wrong! It's shared to Google company. It's not your company, it's not your own server.

For more information check [the following discussing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/248039024?hl=en&sjid=5462172183084772027-EU).

Here some links about which data Google collects:

[Data is collected by Admob](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy/play-data-disclosure#data_collected_and_shared_automatically)

[Data is collected by Firebase Services](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/play-data-disclosure)

You can also use [the following link](https://github.com/Privado-Inc/SDK-Privacy-Report/blob/main/Android%20App%20-%20SDK%20Privacy%20Report.csv) for more libraries (but the info there may be outdated).

At the following page [About data collection controls](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/11580188) Google itself uses word **Share**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the definition of "ephemeral" in the console, Firebase Analytics data is definitely *not* ephemeral because all that data doesn't doesn't just live in memory for real time use.  Apps can collect tremendous amounts of analytics data, and all that has to be stored on disk over a longer term to be useful to service the queries you can perform in the Firebase console.

Comment: Yeah, this one should be obvious. But still what should I choose - *Collected* or *Shared*? My app personally doesn't collect any data to my own's server, the app collects the data only using third-party libs (Firebase / Admob) and send data to third-party servers

Comment: Do you share the data with a third party, via export or console access?  Please read the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=ios#disable_personalized_advertising_features

Comment: I use Firebase Console of my apps only for me. So does it mean that the data is not shared? But usage Google Services itself are not third-party in this case?

Comment: You alone control the access to the data for third parties. If you have any doubts about this, Stack Overflow isn't the right place to ask.  Reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) directly.

Comment: Also one more questions: If I use Firebase/Admob for data collection then *Data is encrypted* or *Data isn’t encrypted*? What should I choose?

Comment: Reach out to Firebase support to get clarity on how the product works if it's not covered in the documentation.

Comment: well actually all of this is marked as "Shared" if we use any third-party libs (Google/Firebase) - `Data sharing - From your app libraries and SDKs. Transferring data collected from your app off a user’s device directly to a third party via libraries and/or SDKs included in your app.` from https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10787469?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwhat-users-will-see-if-your-app-shares-user-data%2Cdata-sharing Also here https://github.com/Privado-Inc/SDK-Privacy-Report/blob/main/Android%20App%20-%20SDK%20Privacy%20Report.csv

Comment: but I see many developers only set the minimum info and mark it only as "Collected" which is totally wrong. Collected is only when you collect for yourself as developer, if you send to any Google service using their libs (or any other organization or just other people/users) then it becomes Shared

Comment: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/11580188?hl=en - `Data collection controls help you better manage the data you share with Google and the bidding ad sources included as part of the AdMob Network`